# How to encrypt cifs mount password?

Tags: encryption, mount, passwords, cifs

In my `/etc/fstab`, I have `credentials=/etc/cifspw`, but the `cifspw` file is in clear. Is there a way to encrypt this file so that the username and password are not in clear, and still be able to mount the shared drive?

Answer (score 4):

Not in a useful way. The SMB client eventually needs access to the cleartext password (or to the NTLM hash, which is password-equivalent as far as protection goes) – and if the SMB client can decrypt it, so can root, and so can anyone else who has access to your /etc.

If you're worried about someone running out with the system disk  (or with the computer in general), use full disk encryption (LUKS). Automatic unlocking could be done using a TPM; there are also ways to bind it to the local network (e.g. using clevis/tang).

Answer (score 1):

You could try `cifscloak`, a simple python wrap around the CIFS mount process.

CIFS passwords are stored encrypted and it can create a systemd file to take care of the mounts at boot time.

https://github.com/sudoofus/cifscloak

```
pip install cifscloak
```

I wrote `cifscloak`. Apologies for the shameless plug, I couldn't help myself.

Comment: No need to apologize! If you wrote something useful, please feel free to share. As long as you are transparent about it; which you are.